# PHP To Pass Selected Value To Query

Tags: php, html, query-string

I am populating a Select with data from my database (A SQL Query).  The options, for example are:

> All Employees
>   
> Jack
>   
> Joe
>   
> Larry
>   
> Bob

Now the text `All Employees` is obviously not an actual employee name, so how would I alter my query based off the value of the Select add a where clause to my sql query?

Obviously `$selectedOption = $_POST['testingselect'];` would store the selected value in the variable `$selectedOption` and I could write my `Where` clause to read (hypothetical)

```
$SQL = "Select * from goneaz where firstname = $selectedOption"
```

However, if `$selectedOption` = All Employees nothing would be returned.  How can I add dynamically add in my SQL Statement that (pseudocode) if $selectedOption = All Employees Then `SQL = "Select * FROM goneaz`.  If $selectedOption <> All Employees THEN `SQL = "Select * FROM goneaz where firstname = $selectedOption`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is concatenate the `WHERE` clause if the $selectedOption <> All Employees.

```
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM goneaz';
if( $selectedOption != 'All Employees' ) {
    $SQL .= " WHERE firstname = '$selectedOption'";
}

//Execute the query
```

Comment: Minor mod, just so it works properly. Hope you dont mind

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the edit. I completely forgot the quotes `''` lol

Comment: Simple string concatenation.  I was overcomplicating it!

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh It happens. Sometimes all you need is a 5 minute break and everything comes back to you.